# Please write a program to print the list after removing even numbers in [5,6,77,45,22,12,24]

Tags: python

```
li = [5,6,77,45,22, 2 ,12,35,57]
for i in li:
    # print(i)
    if (i%2 == 0):
        print(i)
        li.remove(i)
    else:
        pass

print(li)
```

why my output is coming this `[5, 77, 45, 12]` after writing above code

Comment: don't use `li.remove(i)` in a loop

Comment: Create a new list

Comment: append the odd numbers to a new list instead

Comment: Deleting elements while iterating a `list` will skip the next element.

Answer (score 1):

append the odd numbers to a new list instead

```
li = [5,6,77,45,22, 2 ,12,35,57]
li2 = []
for i in li:
    if (i%2 != 0):
        print(i)
        li2.append(i)
    else:
        pass

print(li2)
```

Comment: thnx@stefan_aus_hannover

Comment: you're welcome.